# How to recover VM instance after I receive '(gcloud.compute.instances.move) Internal error' error on google cloud shell?

Tags: google-compute-engine

I have a VM instance on compute engine. I wanted to increase the allocation of GPU's for the VM and hence I was trying to change the zone of the instance from us-central1-a to us-central-1c. I used cloud shell to run the command for migrating the instance and after running for several minutes it gave an internal error with the code 648045795255024598. I refresh my instances page and all of a sudden I don't see my machine listed in the instances page.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/moving-instance-across-zones#limitations), before you can use the 'gcloud compute instances move instancename' command for GCE instances that has GPU enabled, you must ensure that the target zone has a enough gpu quota allocated.

As a suggestion, you may want to check if the [snapshot](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/create-root-persistent-disks#applying_snapshots) of the disk is still available and then recreate the instance.